# Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have a two operator with the same  operator*.One of the get two class parameter and the other gets 2 class parameter and one integer value.Also I want to use assignment operator.I got an error.All of them implemented in header file.Here is codes.

```
A& operator*(A& a1, A& a2)
```

`A& operator*(A& a1, A& a2,int x)`

I got too many parameters for this operator function error for the above.

operator=must be member functon for that:
   `A& operator=(A& a1, A& a2);`
How can I fix this problems.

Comment: @emre Please post your code for the assignment operator and the error that you are seeing.

Comment: Why does your `operator *` take 3 parameters? What is it supposed to do with so many parameters?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot overload `operator*` for 3 parameters. The overloaded `operator*` must either take 0 (pointer overload) or 2 (multiplication overload) parameters.

Even if the code would have been valid, it's still a bad idea to overload operators "non-intuitively". A good rule: overloaded operators should behave as if used with `int`s.

Comment: @ vsoftco Why I cannot take 3 paramaters to the operator*

Comment: @emre That's because of language specifications. C++ allows operator overloading, but there are some rules. This is one of it. And if you think about, the syntax would have been less than pleasant. How would you call such a termnary operator in your code?

Comment: @emre, operator overload does not allow you to change the syntax of the language. It only allows you the freedom to do what you want to do with that syntax.

Comment: @RSahu perfect wording!

Comment: @emre: First you have to explain what you mean by "taking 3 parameters" in `operator *`. How would you use 3 parameters with a `*`??? What are you trying to do? Can you provide an example of `*` being used with 3 arguments?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to figure out what you are trying to do from what you posted, but in any case your `operator *` declaration makes no sense. In C++ language operator `*` can be either binary (multiplication) or unary (dereference), which means that in no case it can be declared with 3 parameters.

The same logic applies to assignment operator, which *must be a member function* that takes 1 argument.

It is not clear from your description why you are trying to declare `operator *` with 3 parameters.

Comment: I have two numbers and I want to multiply them.In the second operator* which has 3 paramaters, I want to get an input from the user and want calculate the result.

Comment: @emre Then I'd suggest to define a different function which takes `int x` as parameter, and in which you call the binary `operator*`, something like `return x * a1 * a2;` (provided that `A` has some conversion operator to `int`, if not, do it step by step).

Comment: @emre: I'm sorry, but "I want to get an input from the user and want calculate the result" does not explain anything. Again, from the beginning of times multiplication operator had *two* operands: one on the left and one on the right. You are trying to write a multiplication operator with *three* operands. Where and how does the third operand fit in?